# How do you get a ruby gem into the include path for "require"

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am creating what I expect to be ruby gem. Anyone have a good link to a tutorial on converting a simple library or plugin to a gem? Also, *especially*, what is the process that Ruby uses to allow the require to find gems? It seems to be something more than putting the files in the gem path (or is my configuration screwed up?).

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's actually not to hard to do this manually.  Let's say you have a library `whatever.rb` that you want to distribute as a gem.

1. make a directory `lib` and put a copy of `whatever.rb` in `lib/whatever.rb`.
2. make a file `whatever.gemspec`, and put the following in there, filling in the appropriate values:

   ```
    Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
      spec.name = 'the-name-of-your-gem'
      spec.version ='0.0.1'

      # this is important - it specifies which files to include in the gem.
      spec.files = ["lib/whatever.rb"]

      # optional, but useful to your users
      spec.summary = "A more longwinded description of your gem"
      spec.author = 'Your Name'
      spec.email = 'you@yourdomain.com'
      spec.homepage = 'http://www.yourpage.com'

      # you did document with RDoc, right?
      spec.has_rdoc = true

      # if you have a ruby forge project
      spec.rubyforge_project = 'your-project-name-on-rubyforge'

      # if you have any dependencies on other gems, list them thusly
      spec.add_dependency('hpricot')
      spec.add_dependency('log4r', '>= 1.0.5')
    end
   ```
3. now, to build the gem, use the `gem build` command:

   ```
   % gem build whatever.gemspec
   Successfully built RubyGem
   Name: the-name-of-your-gem
   Version: 0.0.1
   File: the-name-of-your-gem-0.0.1.gem
   %
   ```
4. You can test locally by using `gem install the-name-of-your-gem-0.0.1.gem`
   To use your library in a script then, simply do the following at the top:

   ```
   require 'rubygems' # puts gem libraries in the require path
   require 'whatever' # loads your library
   ```

For more on what the various settings in the `gemspec` file, check the [GemSpec Reference](http://rubygems.org/read/chapter/20).

Personally, I use rubygems a lot to package executable scripts as well, and find it very handy for that.

Comment: Awesome, this answer made me realize that with bundler by default after building a gem only files added to version control are added to 'spec.files'. That is: `s.files = \`git ls-files\`.split($\)` ignores files you haven't added to git.

Answer (score 2):

There's an [oldish one here](http://drnicwilliams.com/2006/10/11/generating-new-gems/) from Dr Nic, which uses newgem. That is probably a bit out of date now.

Somewhat more recent, we get gemify, which seems to build on the above. [Here's a post about that](http://judofyr.net/posts/introducing-gemify.html)

As far as paths go, once you've executed `gem install <some-useful-stuff>` and your requiring code has either executed `require 'rubygems'` or you've set RUBYOPT=-rubygems (is that Windows only? I'm not sure) then subsequent executions of `require` will also search the gems directory for an appropriate library.

There's also the more explicit (but deprecated) `require_gem` command, which is now just plain `gem`, which allows you to specify version numbers.

Answer (score 2):

For building a ruby gem you may want to look at [newgem](http://github.com/drnic/newgem/tree/master) or [jeweler](http://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler/tree/master).

Comment: There is also a railscast on using bundler to create a new gem. (http://railscasts.com/episodes/245-new-gem-with-bundler)